# c#, build lambda expression dynamically

Tags: c#, expression

I don't have to much experience using expression tree's or building expressions dynamically. However, can somebody help point me in the correct direction following the examples below:

Both use TestTable class

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
public class TestTable
    {
        public int KeyID { get; set; }
        public int KeyID2 { get; set; }
        public string KeyName { get; set; }
    }
```

```
Expression<Func<TestTable, object>> TableKeys = e => new { KeyID = e.KeyID, KeyID2 = e.KeyID2};
```

The value of TableKeys ends up being  = *{new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(KeyID = e.KeyID, KeyID2 = e.KeyID2)}*

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
IList<string> FieldList = new List<string>();
            FieldList.Add("KeyID");
            FieldList.Add("KeyID2");
```

```
var Result = DynamicFields<TestTable>(FieldList);
```

```
 public static Expression<Func<T, object>> DynamicFields<T>(IList<string> fields) 
        {
            var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
            var properties = fields
                .Select(f => typeof(T).GetProperty(f))
                .Select(p => new DynamicProperty(p.Name, p.PropertyType))
                .ToList();
            var resultType = DynamicClassFactory.CreateType(properties, false);
            var bindings = properties.Select(p => Expression.Bind(resultType.GetProperty(p.Name), Expression.Property(source, p.Name)));
            var result = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(resultType), bindings);

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(result, source);
        }
```

The value of Result above ends up being =  {e => new {KeyID = e.KeyID, KeyID2 = e.KeyID2}}

How can I get the code in example 2 above to produce the same output of example 1?

Thanks
Again

Expecting the output of example 2 to produce the output of example 1

Comment: You can't... Expressions would not generate anonymous class

Comment: The other comment isn't quite correct. You can create instances of anonymous objects using expressions. However, anonymous types don't have a default constructor, so you can't create an instance using `Expression.New`.